# Unable to use this.$router.push(' ') inside docRef function

Tags: firebase, vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar

I am trying to use vue-router in my quasar project. `this.$router.push( ' ' )` works everywhere on the page except inside this `docRef` block.

I found out that `this.$router.push` still works in the same component.

This router call works:

```
const userRef = this.$db.collection('users').doc(this.$fb.auth().currentUser.uid)
console.log('your id is' + this.$fb.auth().currentUser.uid)
userRef.set({
  accountUID: this.$fb.auth().currentUser.uid,
  accountChosen: true,
  accountType: 'user'
})
this.$router.push('../user/home')
```

This does not work (in the same component):

```
  var docRef = this.$db.collection('users').doc(uid)
  docRef.get().then(function (doc) {
    data = doc.data().accountType
    if (data === 'user') {
      console.log('account is users')
      console.log(data)
      this.$router.push('./user/home')
    } else if (data === 'truck') {
      console.log('account is a truck')
      this.$router.push('./truck/home')
    } else {
      console.log('in else statement')
    }
  }).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error)
  })
```

Chrome Console Error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '$router' of undefined
        at eval (Check.vue?a4ce:44)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
docRef.get().then(function (doc) {
```

Use:

```
docRef.get().then((doc) => {
```

#### Explanation

The `this` inside an arrow function body block refers to the current context, in your case, the Vue/component instance.

But when you use `function` instead of an arrow function, the `{}` block creates a new context, changing the semantics of `this`, making it point to something else than the `this` outside that function.

In other words, your problem happens because each `function () {}` has its own context (its own `this`), which could be set to something else. Arrow functions, OTOH, inherit the context (the `this`) of where it is declared. In this case, since you are declaring it inside a method, the `this` is the Vue instance. Using an arrow function keeps it. Using a `function()` does not guarantee it (the `this` could be set to something else, which generally is the case).

For futher details, I recommend [MDN - Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).